# Does toothpaste get rid of cold sores?

Tags: alternative-medicine

My girlfriend has told me that the varieties of toothpaste that are actually paste and have some granularity to them (as opposed to gel varieties) get rid of cold sores if applied early in the sore's appearance and regularly afterward.

I've tried it, and I must say it seems to work, at least faster than Carmex or even over the counter things from the pharmacy, and my google searching has yielded a few articles also claiming it works,

http://whatallergy.com/2011-02/fighting-cold-sores

http://www.yumyucky.com/2012/08/natural-cures-home-remedies-for-cold-sores-and-fever-blisters-hsv1.html

but I'm wondering if this really is something I can bank on.

To clarify, I *am* talking about the herpes lip blister variety, and I realize the condition is overall incurable. I'm not asking if toothpaste can cure the condition permanently, I'm just asking if it can make one individual outbreak dissipate faster.

Thanks in advance!